# Sudden Error appears when debugging and hot reloading the app

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm super confused right now. Following error just appeared when I was debugging some parts of my app and suddendly came out of nowhere when I pressed hot reload:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in storeangels...                     
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+1".
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+1".)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja8xh.png)

This is what I found when I searched for the shared_preferences_linux stuff
[image: SharedPreferences Linus]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (5 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/hottube/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

If someone know what to do here I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Delete ```/Users/flutter/.pub-cache/``` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, a colleague was able to give me the solution for my problem.
I had to write following command in the terminal in android studio:

```
flutter pub pub cache repair
```

This fixed the bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `flutter clean` ? This fixed many bugs that I had.